# Weighted Mape in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nan, keras

I'm forecasting daily sales in a supermarket and as a loss function I use the volume weighted mape.

[image: Volume Weighted Mape]

The sum is over the output nodes.

I implemented this in tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def weighted_mape_tf(y_true,y_pred):
tot = tf.reduce_sum(y_true)
wmape = tf.realdiv(tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.subtract(y_true,y_pred))),tot)*100


return(wmape)
```

Unfortunately my output is:

```
Epoch 4/800
0s - loss: 69.3939 - mean_squared_error: 819.6549 - mean_absolute_error: 14.0599
Epoch 5/800
0s - loss: 66.0676 - mean_squared_error: 768.5440 - mean_absolute_error: 13.4120
Epoch 6/800
0s - loss: 63.3000 - mean_squared_error: 728.7665 - mean_absolute_error: 12.8934
Epoch 7/800
0s - loss: 62.0189 - mean_squared_error: 704.7637 - mean_absolute_error: 12.5851
Epoch 8/800
0s - loss: 60.4229 - mean_squared_error: 682.0646 - mean_absolute_error: 12.2814
Epoch 9/800
0s - loss: 59.6329 - mean_squared_error: 674.8835 - mean_absolute_error: 12.1172
Epoch 10/800
0s - loss: 58.5069 - mean_squared_error: 656.2922 - mean_absolute_error: 11.9073
Epoch 11/800
0s - loss: 58.0447 - mean_squared_error: 643.9082 - mean_absolute_error: 11.7542
Epoch 12/800
0s - loss: 56.9352 - mean_squared_error: 628.5248 - mean_absolute_error: 11.5936
Epoch 13/800
0s - loss: 56.3520 - mean_squared_error: 620.7517 - mean_absolute_error: 11.4170
Epoch 14/800
0s - loss: 55.8395 - mean_squared_error: 610.4476 - mean_absolute_error: 11.2979
Epoch 15/800
0s - loss: inf - mean_squared_error: 611.3271 - mean_absolute_error: 11.2931
Epoch 16/800
0s - loss: nan - mean_squared_error: nan - mean_absolute_error: nan
Epoch 17/800
0s - loss: nan - mean_squared_error: nan - mean_absolute_error: nan
Epoch 18/800
0s - loss: nan - mean_squared_error: nan - mean_absolute_error: nan
Epoch 19/800
```

As you see after a while it becomes always **NaN**. 
I guess the error is when tot==0, but when I insert a simple if transforming 
tot when 0 I still get NaNs.

Do you have any experience with this issue?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of minutes I found the answer to my problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def weighted_mape_tf(y_true,y_pred):
    tot = tf.reduce_sum(y_true)
    tot = tf.clip_by_value(tot, clip_value_min=1,clip_value_max=1000)
    wmape = tf.realdiv(tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.subtract(y_true,y_pred))),tot)*100#/tot


    return(wmape)
```

I used the clip_by_value to correct the 0s